# How to dismiss an overlay image in Android/Kotlin (setOnClickListener does not work)?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I'm trying to create a overlay transparent background with an image which can be pinch in/out for an Android app and it is developed in Kotlin.

I have this in my activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black_70"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In the fragment:

```
view.setOnClickListener {
            (activity as MainActivity).overlayImage()
...
...
```

which calls:

```
internal fun overlayImage() {
    // val overlay_frame: View by Views.bind(this, R.id.overlay_frame) // also tried this
    val overlay_frame: View = findViewById(R.id.overlay_frame)
    overlay_frame.setOnClickListener {
        // this is NOT called - why?
        println("setOnClickListener executed 000")
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "setOnClickListener hit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        overlay_frame.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    overlay_frame.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val url = "https://example.com/img/service/item1_img_01.jpg"
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, ImageDisplayFragment.newInstance(url)).commit()
}
```

It correctly calls overlayImage() method and the transparent background with the image loaded.

However, the "overlay_frame.setOnClickListener()" method does NOT work. I expect that when the user clicks anywhere on the screen (but not the image) it will execute the setOnClickListnener() method, but it doesn't it. Nothing within the setOnClickListnener() method is executed.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share logcat

Comment: Try setting `android:focusable="true"`and `android:clickable="true"`in the XML on the overlay_frame view

Answer (score 0):

```
view.setOnClickListener {
            (activity as MainActivity).overlayImage()
}
```

The code block will be executed when `view` was clicked.

```
overlay_frame.setOnClickListener {
        // this is NOT called - why?
        println("setOnClickListener executed 000")
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "setOnClickListener hit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        overlay_frame.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

So the same, the code block will be executed when **overlay_frame** was clicked.

According the code you pasted, what you did is just when the view in fragment was clicked then set the click listener in the `overlay_frame` again and again. the click listener block of the `overlay_frame` will never be invoked, because click event not consumed by the `overlay_frame`.

Why your `overlay_frame` click listener not invoked?

In your `activity_main.xml` file, you Activity's FrameLayout size is same as Fragment's FrameLayout.

Because the fragment layout nested in the Activity layout, you set the fragment view click listener, when you click the screen the click event was consumed by the fragment view. so the `activity.overlayImage()` method invoked. And the the clicked event will not pass to the `overlay_frame`.

You can create a click event for the `overlay_frame`

```
view.setOnClickListener {
     (activity as MainActivity).overlayImage()
    // get the overlay_frame from the activity
    val overlay_frame = activity.getOverlayImage()
    overlay_frame.performClick()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I found the answer:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="375dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />
```

The layout width and height was previously "match_parent". It overlaps the entire parent, even the image is smaller. By changing the above, clicking anywhere will dismiss the overlay background and image.

The problem is resolved.

(However, there is another problem of the image not being centered. Anyway this is a different problem.)

Comment: You can use the `overlay_frame.performClick()` to fix the problem with a `match_parent` layout size. Look my answer.

Comment: My answer did not work. Although it did resolved the problem of invoking the setOnClickListenerI(), but the image cannot be expanded beyond the fragment_container size.

Comment: @Magic I don't your method will work because I tested earlier with a println statement and it was not called.

Comment: add `overlay_frame.performClick()` in `the view.setOnClickListener()` not work? Set the `overlay_frame` visible in xml, and debug the code. Check the perform click have been executed or not , and the `listener` of the `overlay_frame` have been executed or not.

Comment: @Magic I tried your code. As expected, it called at the wrong timing. It called when the overlay image is displayed. I need to call the setOnClickListener after the overlay image is displayed, to dismiss it.

Comment: Then you just place `overlay_frame.performClick()` in the right place which you want . What i can do is try my best to told you why your code block not be invoked and told you how to make it execute, but if the timing is not you wish, just place the code in "right" place.

Comment: Specifically, when the background/image is loaded, it is taken over by GestureTransformableImageView which is an extension of ImageView. How do I set a listener for ImageView?

Comment: `GestureTransformableImageView` is the layout of  `ImageDisplayFragment`?  When you commit the fragment transaction, `ImageDisplayFragment` showed on the screen, then get the `MainActivity` reference in you fragment and do the hide logic?